# Best Way To Store and Sort Data in C#

Tags: c#, simulation

I am building a program that will run 10000 iterations on a 6 sets of numbers. These numbers after being put through the iterations and calculated out and sorted in the following fashion.

```
*_Set1_****_Set2_****_Set3_****_Set4_****_Set5****_Set6_*
*********************************************************
**DESC******DESC******DESC******DESC******DESC*****DESC**
*********************************************************
```

Where Set(n) is the set of numbers and DESC is descending order of the numbers.

I have tried doing a `LIST`. But I am very unfamiliar with `LIST` and I'm not even sure it's what I'm looking for. I'll give you an example of what I was doing with the `LIST`

```
//Created a Output Class for Sim
 public class MC_OUT
    {

       public double output;
       public double OOIP;
       public double OGIP;
       public double EURO;
       public double EURG;
       public double rAREA;
       public double calcEURO;
       public double calcEURG;

        public MC_OUT(double output, double OOIP, double OGIP, double EURO, double EURG, double rAREA, double calcEURO, double calcEURG) { 
        this.output = output;
        this.OOIP = OOIP;
        this.OGIP = OGIP;
        this.EURO = EURO;
        this.EURG = EURG;
        this.rAREA = rAREA;
        this.calcEURO = calcEURO;
        this.calcEURG = calcEURG;


        }

//Declared list before Monte Carlo Sim.
List<MC_OUT> mcout = new List<MC_OUT>();


//Ran Code to Perform Calculations
//Then Executed this at End
 if (OOIP >= 0 && OGIP >= 0)
        {
            mcout.Add(new MC_OUT(NormSInv((i - .5) / iter), OOIP, OGIP, EURO, EURG, rAREA, EURO / (rAREA * rNET_H * rGCF) * 1000, EURG / (rAREA * rNET_H * rGCF) * 1000));
        }
//Then I got confused and couldn't figure out how to sort and then access the needed
 //information
```

So I guess after all this junk my main question would be  **What is the most effective way to store this information and could someone please direct me to an appropriate tutorial?!**

Thanks!

Comment: @jsmith Well the program will need to access it at a later time because those numbers are dependent on another calculation.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. Are having trouble trying to loop through a list, or doing some calculations with the list, or what? If your lists are supposed to be a set of N values, then there is a Tuple class which may be better suited for your situation.

Comment: @KendallFrey Sorry for my vagueness. I had trouble trying to explain myself so confusion was expected. Each set will hold 10000 numbers, which are calculated in code that I left out. Within this set, I need to order the numbers in descending order. I am looking at the Tuple class. It might be what I need. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: If you need to ensure that the data is always sorted, why not just use a [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)? It will keep your list sorted at all times for you. It does however have an interface like a `Dictionary` so just be aware of that. So you won't be able to access items by index normally like a regular list, only by the sort key.

Comment: @JeffMercado great comment. Had no idea that even existed. I will look into that for sure. `SortedList` looks very promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have created a list you can access the data by an index. For Example:

```
var firstRecord = mcout[0];
var firstEURO = firstRecord.EURO;
```

Or:

```
var firstEURO = mcout[0].EURO
```

If you want to sort the data it can be as simple as this.

```
var sortedData = mcout.Orderby(x => x.OOIP);
```

The above will sort the data based on one of the current properties you have. If you need to sort it differently you may need to think about adding another property to your object that would be better suited for sorting.

It is also easy to enumerate through the data with a foreach loop, or a for loop.

```
foreach (var mc in mcout)
{
    var euro = mc.EURO;
}

for (int i = 0; i < mcout.Count; i++)
{
    var euro = mcout[i].EURO;
}
```

Collections are something very widely used, and there are numerous types!! You will want to get to know them, and how to use them. If you google C# collections you will get a lot of information/tutorials. Here's an [MSDN tutorial on collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288462%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). I could keep going on about how to access and use them, but there is really so much that you will need to dive in and start learning it through the information on the web. Hopefully the above examples, and links I have given you can get you started! Cheers!

Comment: I see...now could I perform this on each set ( because I need each set in descending order) and assign each set its own `var`? And how would I go about accessing the numbers inside of this var?

Comment: Ahhh you have gave me a myriad of information. I shall consume it at once. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ThundaUp Anytime for a fellow Thunder fan! Have to take care of my fellow Oklahomans.

Comment: I seriously wish I had the privilege of up-voting comments. Thunder all the way. NBA CHAMPIONSHIP NEXT YEAR!